# Input script of Mix Shader node for create link?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shader-nodes

I am scripting an add-on and I need to create link between Glossy BSDF node and Mix shader node's "shader"
`material_realistic_gold.node_tree.links.new(BsdfGlossy3_node.outputs[0], MixShader_node.outputs.inputs[0])`
This is not working and get an error

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yeung\Downloads\Shader 1.0\Script 001.blend\test.py", line 237, in execute
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'inputs'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

What is the script of input shader of Mix material node?[image: want to script shader connect like this]

Comment: My 2c worth here is try and work out the error from the error message before asking a question here.  Even to the extent of disconnecting from the net.  (for a period of time)  This applies to me too... often  weighing up helpful vs distraction.  Take a  closer look at `MixShader_node.outputs.inputs`

Comment: Okay, I solved the answer finally

Answer (score -1):

I finally figure it out
I need to type
`material_realistic_gold.node_tree.links.new(MixShader_node.inputs[1], BsdfGlossy3_node.outputs[0])`